# Android : UDP multicast on HTC phones

Tags: android, udp, multicast

Ok I've written an application that sends and receives multicast UDP packets. The application works perfectly on my Samsung S3 but it doesn't receive any packets on HTC Explorer running Android 2.3.5. On further research I've found out that some phones do not support UDP multicasting altogether. I want to make sure my application works on all phones. Can we enable multicasting on HTC phones? And if not is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: "I've found out that some phones do not support UDP multicasting altogether". Reference?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on the HTC One running Android 4.1.2

Here's a solution that solved it for me from an [Android bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8407#c35):

```
Wanting to receive broadcasts in a async routine I now use the following code just before the loop where the broadcast messages are received:

WifiManager wifi;
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
MulticastLock ml = wifi.createMulticastLock("just some tag text");
ml.acquire();

When the asynctask stops I do a 
ml.release();
```

I also had to include the following in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```